# Renglones NA al importar CSV y aplicar un as.tbl

Tags: r, csv, importación

Que tal he estado importando archivos en xlsx (`read_excel`) y me ha corrido bien mi Rscript pero a la hora de importar el mismo archivo en csv, me aparece el primer renglon con NAs

Este es un data.frame despues de un `as.tbl` con xlsx

```
str(t)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto pasa cuando la fuente es un csv

ESTO HACE QUE LOS RESULTADOS ME LOS ARROJE EN NA Y NO GRAFICA,
ALGUNA SUGERENCIA ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#INICIA CODIDO DE COMPARACION Y REFERENCIA, EXTRACION DE DATA PARA EL CALCULO

library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(graphics)
library(stats)
library(readr)


CLAVES_SURTIDOR <- read.csv("/home/po11/Desktop/CLAVES_SURTIDOR.csv", 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
TIEMPOS_SURT <- read.csv("/home/po11/Desktop/T_S.csv", stringsAsFactors= 
FALSE)

surt <- data.frame(CLAVES_SURTIDOR, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tsu <- data.frame(TIEMPOS_SURT, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tsur <- transform(tsu, FECHA.EN.COLA = as.POSIXct(FECHA.EN.COLA,"%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S"),FECHA.DE.ASIGNACION = as.POSIXct(FECHA.DE.ASIGNACION,"%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S"),FECHA.DE.CONFIRMACION = as.POSIXct(FECHA.DE.CONFIRMACION,"%Y- 
%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),FECHA.EN.ENTREGAS = as.POSIXct(FECHA.EN.ENTREGAS, "%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S" ))

tablaf <- left_join(surt,tsur)

t <- as.tbl(tablaf)

tdes <-  mutate(t, TIEMPO.DE.SURTIDO = (FECHA.DE.CONFIRMACION - 
FECHA.DE.ASIGNACION)) 

timppp <- mutate(tdes, TIEMPO.PROMEDIO.POR.PARTIDA = (TIEMPO.DE.SURTIDO / 
PARTIDAS.DEL.TICKET))

tabla_calculada_gral <- mutate(timppp, TIEMPO.EN.COLA = (FECHA.DE.ASIGNACION 
- FECHA.EN.COLA))
```

Comment: ¿Por que usas `as.tbl`, si ya `read_excel` te entrega un `tibble`?

Comment: Bueno importe dos archivos de excel,  use un `left_join` para que hiciera una comparacion/filto , después viene el `as,tbl` para realizar una operaciones aritmeticas con `mutate`, tal vez redunde mucho, soy principiante, pero con excel no da problema me corre perfecto

Comment: Es un comportamiento muy raro y no me parece que tenga que ver con el `as.tbl`, te sugiero que compartas el código completo para ver dónde eventualmente podría estar el problema. Saludos.

Comment: añadi el codigo para una mejor idea

Comment: Como primera observación: no pegues imágenes cuando se trate de código, no se puede hacer copy & paste y no sirve para inexar el contenido. Lo segundo que puedo comentarte es que revises el `left_join()` es posible que ahí justamente se produzcan estos `NA`, por valores que matchean en una tabla pero no en la otra. Suerte.